# Uninstalling mcafee antivirus

Tags: uninstall, antivirus

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed mcafee antivirus. But now I am unable to uninstall it.

While running command `sudo dpkg --purge mfert` it gives the error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of mfert:
 mfecma depends on mfert.

dpkg: error processing package mfert (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mfert
```

How can I uninstall mcafee antivirus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

press <kbd>CTRl</kbd>+<kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to switch to a terminal and try to remove.. using commands ..

"The following commands will cleanly uninstall and remove package-related database entries from the system database. No additional commands are needed."

`sudo dpkg --purge mfecma`

`sudo dpkg --purge mfert`

** if you still receive the error, you may use `--force-all`

Eg

```
 sudo dpkg --purge --force-all mfecma
```

"If the folders still exist, the following commands can be executed to remove agent-specific folders:"

`sudo rm –rf /opt/McAfee/cma`

`sudo rm – rf /etc/cma.d`

Then switch back to your desktop with <kbd>CTRl</kbd>+<kbd>ALt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

Removal commands source https://community.mcafee.com/thread/73281

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 approach that worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get purge isecesp isecespaac isecespfileaccess isectp mcafeert mfecma mfedx mfert
```